# I've been having/I have had a headache since I woke up

Tags: present-perfect, progressive-aspect, past-simple

> I've been having a headache since I woke up.

vs

> I've had a headache since I woke up.

*English Grammar in Use* suggests the latter. But what should I do if I want to emphasize the painful feeling rather than just the state?

Answer (score 5):

Either construction is fine. You can say, for example,

> I've had this **bad** headache since I woke up.

(Or nasty, or painful, or whatever other adjective you like.)

"Have been having" emphasizes more the headache *as you're currently experiencing it*; "have had" emphasizes more *how long* it's been going on for. However, these implications are fairly subtle.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the verb 'have' in a progressive form to say that someone has an illness or disease (The Free Dictionary).  So the correct sentence is:

I have had a headache since I woke up.

If you want to emphasize your headache, you can say:

I have had really a headache.....

I have had a splitting/bad/nasty headache.

Answer (score 1):

You indeed cannot use *have been having* to mean *have had*. That's because *have been having* has a key aspect that's lacking in  the other: that of habitual action.

> I**’ve been having** headaches in the mornings ever since I was in that car accident last autumn.
>
> I**’ve been having** someone look in on the children during the day while I’m at work.
>
> He**’s been having** his teeth whitened.
>
> But more recently, though, Annie **had been having** a relationship with Edward Stanely, a bricklayer's mate. (From *Jack the Ripper: A Killer Slops Not* by Kevin Carmichael)

In answer to the question of how to emphasize the painful feeling, you do that by suitably qualifying *headache*:

> I’ve had a **terrible** headache since I woke up this morning.
>
> ”Right now I have a **God awful** headache. Could you bring me a couple of aspirins and a strong cup of coffee?” he asked. (From *Kiss the Fly Goodbye* by Jo Anne Bunyak)

Sometimes it’s spelled *a godawful headache*.